# copying mutlple files from s3 to redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, copy, amazon-redshift

I was actually trying to copy the data from S3 to Redshift. There are 4 files in the S3 bucket folder which are of 700k records each.

When I am trying to copy that four files to a table in Redshift. only the first file is copying to redshift. other files are not copying.

I tried using manifest file and specified manifest in the copy command but  it did not work

Please help me

Comment: can you post the COPY commands you tried and the manifest file?

Comment: Are all four files in the same format (same columns)? Have you examined the `STL_LOAD_COMMITS` and `STL_LOAD_ERRORS` tables?